# When using this code, during redirect to another module, js code of that module not loaded/used. It holds the previous data

Tags: node.js

**Basically in am making an HMVC framework for node.js where i am getting some issues.**

```
app.get('*.html', function(req, res){
    require("./../modules"+res.req.url.split('.')[0]+"/ui"+res.req.url.split('.')[0]+".njs");
    app.use('*/ui',express.static('modules' + res.req.url.split('.')[0] + '/ui'));
    app.use('*/ui',express.static('modules' + res.req.url.split('.')[0] + '/ui'));
    res.sendFile(dirName + 'modules/' + res.req.url.split('.').join('/index.'));
});
```

**I expected it will use js file of login module but it used the js of home module. that was the first module that was called.**

Comment: This looks like dangerous code to me because it loads code on the server and runs it from a path that an attacker can make be anything they want and it can fetch somewhat arbitrary files from the server.

Comment: Also, registering two new `express.static()` middleware calls on every single *.html request does not seem like it's correct.  You can easily get thousands of these middleware registered, even all to identical paths.

Comment: You may need to back up and describe what problem you're really trying to solve because this does not look like the right way to solve it.

Comment: I can't tell from your question, but is it relevant that modules are cached, so if you try to load the same filename with `require()` that you've already previously loaded, it will just return the cached module handle.  It won't load or run the code again.

Comment: Its ok! I got my solution.

Comment: The procedure here if you solve your own problem is that you clarify the question and post your own solution so we can all see what solved it or you delete your question.  The idea is that you don't leave an unclear question just sitting here with no answer as that does nobody any good.